# Question about the definition of Outward/Inward pointing vector in Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to figure out what g(x) in the follwoing definition is supposed to be. Unfortunately I don't find anything about it in previous sections of the book, which is Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach, by Hubbard.

Many thanks in advance.
[image]

---

This slighty modified version is clearer, I think:

[image]
It is from
[https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/~jeggers/math31ch/pieces.pdf](https://mathweb.ucsd.edu/%7Ejeggers/math31ch/pieces.pdf)
[image]
[image]

Comment: Look at the definition of manifold with boundary.

Comment: @TedShifrin In the definition there is $G=(G_{1},...,G_{k})$, but no $g$. Is it a typo by any chance?

Comment: I don’t have the book. This definition is full of notation that is hard to guess.

Comment: @TedShifrin I added the definition.

Comment: Note Definition 6.6.2 and $g$.